# Perfectly smooth looped eased css animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to animate an element to slowly move from left to right a small distance and do it in a smooth way but the result is not very good.

Here is what I have so far:

```
.animate_sideways{animation:sideways 5s linear infinite; animation-timing-function: ease-in, ease-in-out;};
@keyframes sideways {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
}
```

Comment: note that the `0%` will be `translate(0)` so you will have a jump from -30px to 0

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the missing start point in the `keyframes` for the `transform` attribute.

A minor tweak to your code should correct the issue.

A different `animation-timing-function` value or time frame (less that 5s for example)  may suit you better as well.

```css
.contain { width:100% }
.animate_sideways {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:#482;
  animation:sideways 5s linear infinite;
  animation-timing-function:ease-in, ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes sideways {
  0% { transform: translateX(-30px) }
  50% { transform: translateX(30px) }
  100% { transform: translateX(-30px) }
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
<div class="animate_sideways"></div>
</div>
```